# What does "Don't hesitate and call 911" mean?

Tags: american-english

Does it mean I should or shouldn't call 911?

Is it an implicit form of speaking?

It's ambiguous.

Comment: I've never actually heard it phrased this way. Far more common (as far as I'm aware) is *Don't hesitate* ***to*** *call 911.*

Comment: The meaning is probably "don't hesitate **to** call 911" (though one would have to examine the context to be sure).   This is a common twisting of English syntax, probably most often seen in people who speak a "rural" dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended to be interpreted as:

> (Don't hesitate) and (call 911).

Not as:

> Don't (hesitate and call 911).

It could be made clearer with a period or a semi-colon.

> Don't hesitate. Call 911.

Comment: People might pause too long at the period (in *Don't hesitate. Call 911.*)  and never call 911; perhaps that's why it is constructed as one sentence.

Comment: In this case I would consider "and" to be used as a preposition, similar to "to", not a conjunction.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that our ability to confidently say that it means the first, and not the second, is based on our understanding of what it is about, and on our making some reasonable assumptions about the circumstances in which it would be uttered. So far as its *grammatical* structure is concerned, it is ambiguous between the two interpretations.

Comment: @jsw29 Agree 100%.

Answer (score 3):

during the last 70 or so years, there has been a growing practice of substituting ‘and’ for ‘to’ after so-called ‘modals’.  Teachers used to correct this as careless slang.  I doubt if you could find it in the Times or in formal writing generally.

> Don’t you try and get round me with flattery.

In fact I have only come across ‘try and’.  It makes sense because (a) there is nothing else it can mean, and (b) it is now common enough to be familiar.  There is not need to grace it with a grammatical explanation, beyond saying that ‘and’ after ‘try’ can serve the role of ‘to’.

‘Hesitate and’ is new to me.

Comment: Did you try and fail to find other uses for "try and"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don’t understand the question.    I cannot think of a usage of ‘and’ in place of ‘to’ with any other verb than ‘try’ (and ‘hesitate’, of course, if that is not a one-off).  So far I have not found a search question that yields any result.  I’ll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

It means that, once calling 911 is definitely in order, you must not hesitate, not even for a moment; but rather reach for the phone and call it right away.

No more and no less.

Answer (score -1):

You should call 911 without hesitation, because if you think in calling 911 then it means you need it. Do you understand the meaning of hesitation? Hesitation example: "Should I call or not 911?". Hope helping you. Cheers.

Please refer to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hesitating to see samples and meanings.